# how i know the percentage of completeness of the document mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, callback, backend

If I have a collection of 100 documents, how do I know the percentage of completion of every   documents?

I thought that I would make a function by wrapping all the documents and see what is available and what will be returned to you, and make a calculation and see the percentage.

un the end i trying to figure how many fields in your documents are filled?

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what "complete" means in your use case?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your question is vague, but I'm gonna go on a limb here and guess that you are trying to figure how many fields in your documents are filled?

Comment: yes i  trying to figure how many fields in your documents are filled?